# VirtualBox Kernel Module Installing Issue

Tags: centos, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I installed VirtualBox, in the first run i got this warning:

> > WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
> >              available for the current kernel (3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.x86_64) or it failed to
> >              load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
> >                sudo ***/sbin/rcvboxdrv setup***

After launching this command, I got:

> sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv
>
> setup Bad argument setup

I tried another way which is the following commands:

> /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
>
> bash: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: No such file or directory

Last way that I tried:

> /usr/lib/virtualbox/boxdrv.sh setup
>
> Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                         [  OK  ]
>
> Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules            [  OK  ]
>
> Removing old VirtualBox pci kernel module                  [  OK  ]
>
> Removing old VirtualBox netadp kernel module               [  OK  ]
>
> Removing old VirtualBox netflt kernel module               [  OK  ]
>
> Removing old VirtualBox kernel module                      [  OK  ]
>
> Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSdepmod: 
>   ... *Some Warnings* ... [  OK  ]
>
> **Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                     [FAILED]**

What can i try?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hit the same issue today after upgrading to 5.0.14 (I am on Ubuntu 15.10, using the official Virtualbox apt repo)

I fixed it with:

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, over several systems it was enough. Little note, in one case i needed to disable the 'Secure Boot' feature using Bios.

Comment: I wonder why Oracle doesn't either do this for you (it seems to be required after every kernel upgrade) or at least suggest you run this manually instead of something which produces an error?

Comment: disabled secure boot on bios setup solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try new installation media (a new OS).  Despite Oracle owning it, I have found that even relatively new versions of Oracle Linux are not always compatible with relatively new versions of Oracle Virtualbox.

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was the "Secure Boot" feature. Disabling it in boot options fixed this issue.