# Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Virtualbox on my desktop:

Processor: AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor × 8
OS type: 64bit
Ubuntu 16.04

Here's a snapshot of my bash history:

```
35  sudo dpkg -i /home/andy/Downloads/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb 
36  sudo apt-get install libqt4-opengl
37  sudo apt-get -f install
38  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
39  sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
40  virtualbox
41  sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
42  dmesg | grep VirtualBox
43  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
44  sudo modprobe -v vboxdrv
45  dmesg
46  sudo systemctl status vboxdrv
```

Expanding on those commands a little:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found

$ virtualbox
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.4.0-22-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

$ sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox pci kernel module ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox netadp kernel module ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox netflt kernel module ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox kernel module ...done.
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why)
```

From [VirtualBox Kernel Module Installing Issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255519/virtualbox-kernel-module-installing-issue)

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

produces:

```
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
(modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why)

$ dmesg
[ 5845.992334] capability: warning: `VirtualBox' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
[ 6004.050016] show_signal_msg: 33 callbacks suppressed
[ 6004.050022] Chrome_ChildThr[7835]: segfault at 0 ip 0000562e33366a24 sp 00007f278abfe360 error 6 in plugin-container[562e3335e000+3d000]
[ 6050.579010] Chrome_ChildThr[10708]: segfault at 0 ip 0000563aaf904a24 sp 00007f51711fe360 error 6 in plugin-container[563aaf8fc000+3d000]
```

So the 'modprobe vboxdrv failed' is problematic. A Google reveals a similar story over here: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11577

I checked my BIOS, in CPU Configuration / SVM this is set to 'enabled'.

```
This secure virtual mode will let you run multiple OS (guest) on the same physical hardware with the hypervisor layer.
```

Despite all this VMs still won't launch?

Thwarted by `modprobe vboxdrv kernel modules` argh!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Disable the secure boot on your BIOS settings : Secure boot prevent unsigned modules to be loaded.

2) According to [Virtualbox-wiki](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) you need to install `dkms` module:

> Ubuntu/Debian users might want to install the dkms package to ensure that the VirtualBox host kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt and vboxnetadp) are properly updated if the linux kernel version changes during the next apt-get upgrade.

Type the following command to install `dkms`:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Then you can install Virtual-box following the steps described on Virtualbox/Wiki

Comment: Brilliant advice this GAD3R. Bit of a hairy moment when one has to go into Advanced BIOS and delete Platform Keys to disable Secure Boot but it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 16.04LTS kernel module `4.4.0-22-generic` I had to run:

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms`.

In my case it was asking to disable secure UEFI. As a side note, the password requested for confirmation needs to be at least 8 characters long.